# Go to another page through the Omnibox on the top bar of the browser

Tags: reactjs, next.js, browser, web-frontend, custom-error-pages

I want to go to another page of my project from the top bar of the browser, but it gives me a 404 error
Is the problem with my codes?
Or did I give the wrong address?
I put a photo of the directory and the register page itself
I called http://localhost:3000/auth/register like this

How do I solve the problem and how do I know where the problem is?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITLYu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.